# Scalloped potatoes and oven fried pork copsihave scl

Tags: baking

I have scalloped potatoes that need to cook at 450 for 25 minutes and ocean fried pork chops that need to cook at 425 for 25 minutes.  How much longer will scalloped potatoes need to cook at 425?

Answer (score 3):

Potatoes are forgiving; they can bake longer.

the temperature difference between 425 and 450 is not big, i would expect them to take about the same time.

To be on the safe side, I would put the potatoes 15 minutes before the pork and bake them up nicely and take them out when they are ready.

curious what is "ocean fried pork chops" ? I assume it's a typo for "oven fried pork chops" ?